# Pass input element value (php) to Sweetalert javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am pretty new to programming, so hoping to get some answers here

**Background:**
I am using PHP which pulls an object id, and I basically have input type button which once clicked will give an alert to confirm if you want to continue, which once confirmed will update database (say for example recertify).

Achieved it having " and it also provides the basic alert. Now I want to replace this basic alert with SweetAlert, so I had to replace the "a" element with "input".

Below is HTML code

```html
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction();" class="btn btn-info" value="Recertify" />
<input type="hidden" id="recertid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
```

And below is JavaScript

```html
<script>
function myFunction(){
  swal({   
    title: "",   
    text: "Are you sure you want to recertify?",   
    type: "warning",   
    showCancelButton: true,
    showConfirmButton: true,   
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   
    confirmButtonText: "Recertify!",   
    cancelButtonText: "I am not sure!", 
    closeOnConfirm: false,   
    closeOnCancel: false,
  }, 
    function(isConfirm){   
        if (isConfirm) 
    {   
     var sid = document.getElementById("recertid").value;
        swal({
          title: "", 
          text: "Schedule recertified!",
          type: "success",
          timer: 1000
        }, function(){
          window.location = "recertify.php?id=" + sid;
        }

        );   
        } else {
            //return false;     
            swal({
              title: "",
              text: "No action taken!",
              type: "error",
              timer: 1000
              });   
            } 
        });
}
</script>
```

As you can see that using window.location required id is passed to another php

No issues with the alert, works perfectly fine. The issue is that only the first $id in the table row gets passed in the window.location.

How can we pass value based on the button clicked in the row ? Tried to look for answers online but could not find a right way

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am understanding correctly, you have several rows with buttons. You need to pass the respective clicked button's row 'recertid / id' to your PHP script through window.location.

Lets pass the 'id' value to the function "myFunction('$id')"

```html
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction('<?php echo $id; ?>');" class="btn btn-info" value="Recertify" />
<input type="hidden" id="recertid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>

<script>
function myFunction(recertid){
  swal({   
    title: "",   
    text: "Are you sure you want to recertify?",   
    type: "warning",   
    showCancelButton: true,
    showConfirmButton: true,   
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   
    confirmButtonText: "Recertify!",   
    cancelButtonText: "I am not sure!", 
    closeOnConfirm: false,   
    closeOnCancel: false,
  }, 
    function(isConfirm){   
        if (isConfirm) 
    {   
        swal({
          title: "", 
          text: "Schedule recertified!",
          type: "success",
          timer: 1000
        }, function(){
          window.location = "recertify.php?id=" + recertid;
        }
        );   
        } else {
            //return false;     
            swal({
              title: "",
              text: "No action taken!",
              type: "error",
              timer: 1000
              });   
            } 
        });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks